# How to serve subfolder as root using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is my server block at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain`;

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Inside my `/var/www/html/` folder I have `folder1` and `folder2`. I can access both of these at `mydomain.com/folder1` and `mydomain.com/folder2`. `folder1` is currently being served as `mydomain.conf/folder1` so no issues on that one.

However, I want to server `folder2` as my main domain. So when I access `mydomain.com` it should serve whatever insides `/var/www/html/folder2`.

I literally tried every single answer I could find online (and I'm aware there are dozens of similar questions online) yet none of them worked for me. Sorry I'm a bit rookie and I appreciate your understanding.

EDIT: Both `folder1` and `folder2` contain PHP apps.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option is to use

```
root /var/www/html/folder2;
```

and put `folder1` under the `/var/www/html/folder2`. If you can't do it for some reason, your second option is to use the following config (I omit the `try_files` directive from your root location since `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` is a default behavior):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/folder2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {}

    location /folder1/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

If you want the `/folder1` URL to be workable too, you either change `location /folder1/ { ... }` to `location /folder1 { ... }` or add an explicit redirect (this won't needed if you put your `folder1` under the `/var/www/html/folder2`, in that case this redirect will be issued automatically):

```
location = /folder1 {
    return 301 /folder1/$is_args$args;
}
```

I prefer the second way since using the first one you made any route started with `/folder1` prefix (but different from it, e.g. `/folder10`) unavailable for your root web app.